# does anyone know how to perform stepwise regression in django app

Tags: django, web-applications, django-urls

I am developing a Django app where in the user will upload a .csv file or excel file by clicking  a file upload option and also will have to choose between 4 options 1. stepwise regression 2. LASSO 3.Ridge regression 4.Random forest. and it will show the results in the same page. i have developed the app up to file upload option and the file is also stored in app when uploaded in media. my templates include inde.html, fileupload.html. I need code to do the above mentioned steps. i am beginner and i have to submit this tomorrow to my professor. can someone help me?...

I have tried but I am getting  errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.